# Export to .csv with triple header row in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have data like this below in csv file:

```
CustomerID, Name,    Email
1,          Name A,  email1@gmail.com
2,          Name B,  email2@gmail.com
3,          Name C,  email3@gmail.com
```

The code for export to .csv file is working good. Delivered data like above. But I need to change the format of .csv file like this.

```
CustomerID
Name
Email
1
Name A
email1@gmail.com
CustomerID
Name
Email
2
Name B
email2@gmail.com
CustomerID
Name
Email
3
Name C
email3@gmail.com
```

Below is my code :

```
 public List<CustomerInfo> GetCustomers()
    {
        List<CustomerInfo> customerList = new List<CustomerInfo>();
        customerList.Add(new CustomerInfo { CustomerID = 1, Name = "Name A", Email = "email1@gmail.com" });
        customerList.Add(new CustomerInfo { CustomerID = 2, Name = "Name B", Email = "email2@gmail.com" });
        customerList.Add(new CustomerInfo { CustomerID = 3, Name = "Name C", Email = "email3@gmail.com" });
        return customerList;
    }


 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb += sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", "CustomerID", "Name", "Email") + Environment.NewLine);
        List<CustomerInfo> customerList = GetCustomers();
        foreach (CustomerInfo objCustomer in customerList)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", objCustomer.CustomerID.ToString(), objCustomer.Name, objCustomer.Email) + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.csv" + "\"");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

I already try to make the StringBulder with += just to repeat the next row, and add another variable byte[]. But It still not work. It show me error that sting builder can not do with +=. Maybe I'm wrong to make it. But I have no idea how to make the triple row header on csv file. I'm searching so much on google, but I still not found the format .csv that I want.

Comment: instead of commas, use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion. It's work dude :D

Comment: Looks like someone made more effort below - please try and mark if correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string headers = "CustomerID" + Environment.NewLine
        + "Name" + Environment.NewLine
        + "Email";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<CustomerInfo> customerList = GetCustomers();
    foreach (CustomerInfo objCustomer in customerList)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(headers);
        sb.AppendLine(objCustomer.CustomerID);
        sb.AppendLine(objCustomer.Name);
        sb.AppendLine(objCustomer.Email);
    }

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    if (bytes != null)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.csv" + "\"");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Though to be honest, this is no longer `CSV`, its regular text, so a more appropriate `Content-Type` might be `text/plain`...

Comment: I have no to much knowledge about csv. This is what the company want is like that format. May I ask you something? so this is no longer csv as you said. Is it because I want triple header row ?

Comment: It's because 1) There are no commas separating the fields and 2) Each field is on a separate line. CSV is short for *comma separated values*, no commas = no CSV. Don't worry too much about it though. If that is what they want, then give them that...

Comment: ohh yes. I don't know also why they want it like that. :D by the way thank you so much for your explanation. you are right..

Comment: I can see that you have posted your own answer as well. It's considered polite to accept (and upvote once you have enough reputation) the answer that helped you, even if it's not *exactly* what you ended up using. That reward the person who wrote the answer with reputation points. You don't get reputation for accepting your own answer I believe...

Comment: Hi dude, I don't need reputation here. I just want to find what I want to search about. And if someday there is someone having the same problem like me he/she will know the ending of this question which is right. If you want reputation. I can vote for you. Thank you so much and I appreciate so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nick.McDermaid user1429080 comment. I change to this. And it's work

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string headers = "CustomerID" + Environment.NewLine
                          + "Name" + Environment.NewLine
                          + "Email" + Environment.NewLine;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //sb = sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", "CustomerID", "Name", "Email") + Environment.NewLine);

        List<CustomerInfo> customerList = GetCustomers();
        foreach (CustomerInfo objCustomer in customerList)
        {
            //sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", objCustomer.CustomerID.ToString(), objCustomer.Name, objCustomer.Email) + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append(headers);
            sb.Append(objCustomer.CustomerID.ToString());
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(objCustomer.Name);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(objCustomer.Email);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.csv" + "\"");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much All for your comment. Help me so much.. :D